# Nearly circular orbits (and their angular frequency)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, angular-velocity, approximations

In 'nearly' circular motion, the radius is not constant. If the force is central the and the angular momentum is still conserved, we have a central force:

[image]

where $r_0$ is equilibrium position.

For this motion, the orbital radius will 'oscillate' due to the centripetal and centrifugal force. However, in such motion, I am not sure how the angular frequency is given by:

[image]

whereby $Ω$ is the angular frequency due to the 'oscillating' radius, and ω is the angular frequency of the orbit itself.

Any help in explaining this concept and explaining how the angular frequency is derived will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conservation of energy
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\omega^2) + U(r) = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2 + \frac{L^2}{2mr^2} + U(r)
$$
yields the equation of motion
$$
m\ddot{r} = \frac{L^2}{mr^3} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial r} = - \frac{\partial U_\text{eff}}{\partial r}.
$$
For a circular orbit with radius $r_0$, we have $\ddot{r}\equiv 0$, so that
$$\left.\frac{\partial U_\text{eff}}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0}=0\qquad
\text{and}\qquad
\frac{L^2}{mr_0^3} = \left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0}\quad.
$$
For nearly circular stable orbits, we can write $r = r_0 +x$, with $x\ll r_0$, and the equation of motion becomes
$$
m\ddot{x} = -\left.\frac{\partial U_\text{eff}}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0+x}\quad.
$$
We can Taylor expand the right-hand side up to first order in $x$:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial U_\text{eff}}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0+x} = 
\left.\frac{\partial U_\text{eff}}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0} +
x\left.\frac{\partial^2 U_\text{eff}}{\partial r^2}\right|_{r=r_0} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)
=
x\left.\frac{\partial^2 U_\text{eff}}{\partial r^2}\right|_{r=r_0} + \mathcal{O}(x^2),
$$
so we obtain
$$
m\ddot{x} + x\left.\frac{\partial^2 U_\text{eff}}{\partial r^2}\right|_{r=r_0} = 0.
$$
This is the equation of a [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator), with frequency
$$
\Omega = \sqrt{\frac{1}{m}\left.\frac{\partial^2 U_\text{eff}}{\partial r^2}\right|_{r=r_0}}\quad.
$$
Your example involves a central force $F(r) = -Kr^n$. The rest is a straightforward calculation.